# How do I create a JPanel with two images where only a part of the one below is shown on mouse over?

Tags: java, image, swing, paintcomponent, mouse-listeners

I am trying to create a button panel where the button that was clicked becomes 'differently colored'; i.e show the background image. p.s I only need this approach(with 2 images), and not anything else. Thanks !

Eg:

```
public class TestPane extends JPanel {      

        private BufferedImage   imgUnclicked;
        private BufferedImage   imgClicked;
        private Point           mousePoint;

        public TestPane() {
            try {
                imgUnclicked = ImageIO.read(new File("C:\\Users\\Me\\Desktop\\tmp\\Uncolored.png"));
                imgClicked = ImageIO.read(new File("C:\\Users\\Me\\Desktop\\tmp\\Colored.png"));
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Spotlight.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }

            addMouseMotionListener(new MouseAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                    mousePoint = e.getPoint();
                    repaint();
                }
            });
        }
    }
    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        //Draw imgClicked
        //Draw imgUnclicked with some rectangular area around mouse click subtracted
    }
}
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No need to reinvent the wheel.  Instead use a `JToggleButton` (appropriately configured).  A button will react to both mouse **and** keyboard input.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.net.*;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;

class ChangeImageOnClick {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        URL url1 = new URL("https://i.stack.imgur.com/gJmeJ.png");
        final Image img1 = ImageIO.read(url1);
        URL url2 = new URL("https://i.stack.imgur.com/wCF8S.png");
        final Image img2 = ImageIO.read(url2);
        Runnable r = new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                JToggleButton btn = new JToggleButton("Click me!");
                btn.setIcon(new ImageIcon(img1));
                btn.setSelectedIcon(new ImageIcon(img2));

                btn.setContentAreaFilled(false);
                btn.setBorderPainted(false);

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, btn);
            }
        };
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(r);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A different idea.  Basically, load an image into a `JLabel`, set the `Layout` of the label and add two opaque components to it.

By using a simple `MouseListener`, you can either make the component invisible or transparent based on your needs...

[image][image]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class HideAndShow {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new HideAndShow();
    }

    public HideAndShow() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        public TestPane() {
            setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            try {
                BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(new File("/Users/swhitehead/Dropbox/MegaTokyo/Haibane_Miho___Take_2_by_garrbage.png"));
                JLabel label = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(img.getScaledInstance(-1, 200, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH)));
                add(label);

                label.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 1));

                JPanel top = new JPanel();
                top.add(new JLabel("Top"));
                JPanel bottom = new JPanel();
                bottom.add(new JLabel("Bottom"));

                MouseAdapter ma = new MouseAdapter() {
                    @Override
                    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                        ((JPanel)e.getComponent()).setOpaque(false);
                        repaint();
                    }
                };

                top.addMouseListener(ma);
                bottom.addMouseListener(ma);

                label.add(top);
                label.add(bottom);
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add an `ActionListener` to your button and call `setIcon` with the `imgClicked`.

Something like this:

```
    JButton btn = new JButton();
    btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            btn.setIcon(imgClicked);
        }
    });
```

Comment: setIcon() scales the background image to button size.In this case, both the foreground and the background are the same, except that the one in the background is colored and the other is not. Which is why I need some solution like area subtract for images.