# How to load an image to a JButton in java?

Tags: java, image, swing, jbutton

I want to load an image to a JButton in a java application so when I click the button to show the image and when I click it again to hide the image.I don't want the image to be loaded to a label but on the button.

Comment: Use the technique shown in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18656168/418556), but replace the first image with one that is the same size as the second, but entirely transparent.

Comment: One related [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11428289/1057230) :-)

Answer (score 5):

I'm thinking in [SWT](http://www.eclipse.org/swt/), but I guess this works for Swing too.

```
final JButton button = new JButton();
final ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(image);
button.setIcon(icon);

button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) { 
         button.setIcon( button.getIcon() == null ? icon : null );
    }

});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
ImageIcon iconStart = new ImageIcon("start.jpg");
JButton bttnStart = new JButton(iconStart);
```