# JLabel coloring and making transparent

Tags: java, swing, colors, jlabel

I'm trying to color and make transparent the same `JLabel` When I click on it.

```
int leftP=4;      //initialized at start of code
if (leftP>0){
        if (lbl.getBackground()!=Color.YELLOW){
            lbl.setBackground(Color.yellow);
            lbl.setOpaque(true);
            leftP--;
        }else{
            lbl.setOpaque(false);
            lbl.repaint();
            leftP++;
        }
}
```

The problem here is that when `leftP>0` if checks if the Background of the Label is already Yellow. if it is ... it uncolor it but if its not  it colors it.
It works for the first time.

1. I click on label and it becomes yellow and `leftP=3`.
2. I reclick on label it becomes without yellow color as background and `leftP=4`.
3. When I click the third time. I expect it to become Yellow with `leftP=3` ... but unfortunately I don't understand why it remains without color and it continues entering in `ELSE` Loop whenever I click on label.

Comment: As an aside.  Use a `JToggleButton` with one colored (default) and one transparent (selected) icon.  Much easier.

Comment: ..e.g. [as seen here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18656168/418556).

Answer (score 1):

setOpaque() will not change the background color, so it is still yellow.

Try

```
lbl.setOpaque(false);
lbl.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
```

Or better use another marker, eg. your own variable.

Answer (score -1):

Add a try catch statement and Remaint the label everytime after color change using lbl.repaint();

```
try{
    int leftP=4;      //initialized at start of code
    if (leftP>0){
        if (lbl.getBackground()!=Color.YELLOW){
            lbl.setBackground(Color.yellow);
            lbl.setOpaque(true);
            lbl.repaint();
            leftP--;
        }else{
            lbl.setOpaque(false);
            lbl.repaint();
            leftP++;
        }
    }
}catch(Exception ee){
ee.printStackTrace();
}
```